# split file address in shell script by special character

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script. I have the file address in the following format:

```
/Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SN/RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg
```

I want to use the SN parameter which is always fixed so as to split the file address and have the following two strings

```
/Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SN
/RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can use the capabilities of bash itself, *parameter expansion with substring removal* to parse the values you need:

```
end="${str##*/SN}"   ## get end
begin="${str%$end}"  ## remove end to get begin
```

This requires no additional subshell or utility.

A short example using your values:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="/Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SN/RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg" 

end="${str##*/SN}"   ## get end
begin="${str%$end}"  ## remove end to get begin

printf "begin: %s\nend  : %s\n" "$begin" "$end"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash splitstr.sh
begin: /Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SN
end  : /RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's|(.*/SN)(/.*)|\1\n\2|' <<< /Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SN/RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg
```

#### Output:

```
/Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SN
/RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg
```

As you can see, you can choose your substitution delimiter, not mandatory to use `s///`

### Edit :

Try this with the same input as [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
perl -pe 's|(.*/SN)(/.*)|$1\n$2|'
```

Comment: I used that but I get /Users/hsn15051/downloads/RandomName1/RandomName2/SNn/RandomNumber/Myimage.jpg. How can I separate these two values and save them into different variables so that I use them in next processing steps?

Comment: Which OS ? Have you GNU sed ?

Comment: Added perl's solution